# Irregular results while prediction identical object on same image

Tags: tensorflow, prediction, object-detection

I used the pre-trained model [faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config) with my own dataset.

I have two issues

1. some objects were not detected, while I learned it, with a high number of steps, and test over the same learning data, but still have some missing data
2. sometimes, the same identical objects predicted correctly on some images and sometimes it got missed, although the objects are identical

Any help would be appreciated.